# Vlookup using python when data given in range

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have two excel files, I want to perform vlookup and find difference of costs using python or even excel.

My files look like this

**source_data.xlsx** contains contains distance covered and their price, example distance range from 1 to 100 should be charged 4800 and distance range from 101 to 120 should be charged 5100.

```
DISTANCE     COST

1-100        4800

101-120      5100

121-140      5500

141-160      5900

161-180      6200

181-200      6600

210-220      6900

221-240      7200
```

**Analysis.xlsx**

```
loading_station  distance_travel     total_cost    status

PUGU                  40                4000       PAID


PUGU                  80                3200       PAID

MOROGORO              50                5000       PAID

MOROGORO              220               30400      PAID

DODOMA                150               5100       PAID

KIGOMA                90                2345       PAID

DODOMA                230               6000       PAID

DODOMA                180               16500      PAID

KIGOMA                32                3000       PAID

DODOMA                45                6000       PAID

DODOMA                65                5000       PAID

KIGOMA                77                1000       PAID

KIGOMA                90                4000       PAID
```

Actual Cost for distance is given in `source_data.xlsx`, I want to check cost in `Analysis.xlsx` if it correspond to Actual value, I want to detect underpayment and overpayment.

Desired Output should be like this, with two column added, `source_cost` which is taken from `source_xlsx` by using `vlookup` and difference which is difference between `total_cost` and `source_cost`

```
loading_station distance_travel total_cost  status  source_cost Difference

PUGU               40                4000     PAID     4800        -800

PUGU               80                3200     PAID     4800        -1600

MOROGORO           50                5000     PAID     4800         200

MOROGORO           220               30400    PAID     6900         23500

DODOMA             150               5100     PAID     5900         -800

KIGOMA             90                2345     PAID     4800         -2455

DODOMA             230               6000     PAID     7200         -1200

DODOMA             180               16500    PAID     6200          10300

KIGOMA             32                3000     PAID     4800          -1800

DODOMA             45                6000     PAID     4800           1200

DODOMA             65                5000     PAID     4800           200

KIGOMA             77                1000     PAID     4800           -3800

KIGOMA             90                4000     PAID     4800           -800
```

My code so far

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# read excel data
source_data = pd.read_excel('source_data.xlsx')
analysis_file = pd.read_excel('analysis.xlsx')
source_data.head(5)
analysis_file.head(5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is a categorical bins problem, I suggest utilizing `cut()` and find the corresponding value.

```
import pandas as pd
# create bins
bh = df_source['DISTANCE'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')).apply(pd.Series).astype(int).values[:,0]
bt = df_source['DISTANCE'].apply(lambda x: x.split('-')).apply(pd.Series).astype(int).values[:,1]
bins = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(bh, bt, closed='both')

print(bins)
###
IntervalIndex([[1, 100], [101, 120], [121, 140], [141, 160], [161, 180], [181, 200], [210, 220], [221, 240]], dtype='interval[int64, both]')
```

As it shown, `IntervalIndex`, `dtype='interval[int64, both]'`

```
# find corresponding values
df_analysis['source_cost'] = pd.cut(df_analysis['distance_travel'], bins=bins).map(dict(zip(bins, df_source['COST']))).astype(int)

# calculation
df_analysis['Difference'] = df_analysis['total_cost'] - df_analysis['source_cost']

print(df_analysis)
###
```

| loading_station | distance_travel | total_cost | status | source_cost | Difference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PUGU | 40 | 4000 | PAID | 4800 | -800 |
| PUGU | 80 | 3200 | PAID | 4800 | -1600 |
| MOROGORO | 50 | 5000 | PAID | 4800 | 200 |
| MOROGORO | 220 | 30400 | PAID | 6900 | 23500 |
| DODOMA | 150 | 5100 | PAID | 5900 | -800 |
| KIGOMA | 90 | 2345 | PAID | 4800 | -2455 |
| DODOMA | 230 | 6000 | PAID | 7200 | -1200 |
| DODOMA | 180 | 16500 | PAID | 6200 | 10300 |
| KIGOMA | 32 | 3000 | PAID | 4800 | -1800 |
| DODOMA | 45 | 6000 | PAID | 4800 | 1200 |
| DODOMA | 65 | 5000 | PAID | 4800 | 200 |
| KIGOMA | 77 | 1000 | PAID | 4800 | -3800 |
| KIGOMA | 90 | 4000 | PAID | 4800 | -800 |

Comment: I get this error NameError: name 'IntervalIndex' is not defined

Comment: Don't copy the stuff under `###`, that's what result I wanna show you.